# Bug: Whenever I'm around Farkas he acts like my follower?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Every time I go to the Companions place and when Farkas is there, he is always following me around and I'm automatically focused to him as if he's talking to me. And when I cancel the talk, 3 seconds later I focus to him again, and again. I have to fast travel away from him for him to stop. I did add him as my follower repeatedly in order to increase my skills and get my money back, but now I see that that may be the source of this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the game from your PS3/ Xbox or PC/ MAC then reinstall the game, but make sure to keep all saved data. 
This should help as it is a way to fix many bugs, I play on the PS3 myself and I had a glitch where whenever I wen't into water and started swimming I deleted it off my PS3 and reinstalled it, fixed the problem completely and I kept all saved game data.

I hope this helped.